# .Net windows app development: Detecting if SSL Client Certificate is required and which ones are valid

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest, client-certificates

In the same way as IE handles the client certificate authentication procedure, I would like to do the same from an installed .Net client app that connects to our web server which has been setup for requiring client certificates.

I know how to open the Select Certificate UI allowing the user to select a client certificate from a list of those that are installed, and then add the certificate to the outgoing HttpWebRequest.

What I can figure out is:

1. How to determine when a client certificate is required by the server. It's not in the HttpResponse. The status code is 403 but I can't read the substatus.
2. How to then filter the client certificates in the UI to list only those that are valid based on the server certificate (issued by?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, and do the server and client certificates need to be issued by the same CA for this to work?

Comment: I just need to know the classes/properties/methods to use, the rest I can research. Thanks